# I cannot return an object until and unless the curly bracket is placed right next to the return statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
compClasses: function() {
    /* IT DOES NOT WORK LIKE THIS */
    return 
    {
        major: this.valA,
        minor: this.valB
    }
    /* BUT WORKS LIKE THIS KINDLY TAKE NOTICE OF THE PLACEMENT OF CURLY BRACKETS */
    return {
        major: this.valA,
        minor: this.valB
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly describe your issue (expected vs actual output) and don't overuse Caps Lock. I can't see the difference in placement of curly brackets.

Comment: I see..I suppose its corrected now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript automatically inserts semicolons (or ends statements) when needed. If you write

```
return
{
    major: this.valA,
    minor: this.valB
}
```

the return statement is executed directly (like if you'd write `return;`). If you write

```
return {
    major: this.valA,
    minor: this.valB
}
```

the complete object is returned instead. The semicolon is added after the object.

---

The rules for automatic insertions of semicolons are as followed ([source](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/)):

1. when the next line starts with code that breaks the current one (code can spawn on multiple lines)
2. when the next line starts with a `}`, closing the current block
3. when the end of the source code file is reached
4. when there is a `return` statement on its own line
5. when there is a `break` statement on its own line
6. when there is a `throw` statement on its own line
7. when there is a `continue` statement on its own line